# Cell padding/spacing in html

Tags: html, padding

I am working on a web page where I have no access to CSS for whatever reason. All I have is HTML. I want to have a "menu" based on an image, there is a table on top of the image and I want to link each cell in the table to a particular page using linked images inside the cells, the images are transparent pngs because I want it to look like user is Clicking on a Squad name. 
See image below:
https://ibb.co/cXjXMVx

[image]

However I ran into a problem where whatever I use the image doesnt cover the full cell size and always has about a 2-3px padding around it.
See here:
https://ibb.co/8B3FmHD

[image]

I've tried so many threads here and turned google inside out and I haven't a clue what I'm doing wrong.

I've tried so many threads here and turned google inside out and I haven't a clue what I'm doing wrong.

```
<table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" style="width: 100%;">
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td style="width: 6.5552%;">
                <br>
            </td>
            <td style="width: 6.3991%;">
                <br>
            </td>
            <td style="width: 6.3991%;">
                <br>
            </td>
            <td style="width: 6.3991%;">
                <br>
            </td>
            <td style="width: 6.3991%;">
                <br>
            </td>
            <td style="width: 6.7113%;">
                <br>
            </td>
            <td style="width: 6.7113%;">
                <br>
            </td>
            <td style="width: 6.3991%;">
                <br>
            </td>
            <td style="width: 6.8673%;"><img align="center" width="100%" class="fr-dib" src="https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/Konuwcb2FAWkOL3_dDzHuYnbfBFJVBAx8wJaIeVvv4k72QNhpY0qMltcK1cNtw7H63cIzhed0ue6QrdvB6Zl=s1600" style="width: 21px; height: 24.2646px;">
```

What am I doing wrong here, any idea how I can fix this without any css ?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Have you thought about just using an image map and creating coordinates to link an area of the circle?


https://www.image-map.net/


https://html.com/images/how-to-make-an-image-map/

`<!-- Image Map Generated by http://www.image-map.net/ -->
<img src="https://i.ibb.co/NnMnQb7/circle.png" usemap="#image-map">

<map name="image-map">
    <area target="" alt="" title="" href="http://www.google.com" coords="201,521,399,669" shape="rect">
</map>`

Comment: I will give it a go, thanks for the help.